# Sending Wrapper object to Apex from Javascript in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura, web-components

I have a question regarding the operation of the wrappers classes in lwc.

I have an apex method which has as an input parameter an object of the wrapper class.

FIRST IMAGE:
[image]

SECOND IMAGE:
[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to send a wrapper object of type "camposFormularioWrapper" from javascript to Apex. In Aura component it is easy, you create an attribute of type "camposFormularioWrapper" such that:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply use a generic object. For example:

```
export default class myComponent extends LightningElement {
  @track someData = {tipoConfiguracion: 'some value', modificacionesElegidas: ['value 1','value 2']}

  // some time later //
  someFunction() {
    validaciones({camposFormulario: this.someData })
    .then(result => { /* handle result */ })
    .catch(error => { /* handle error */ });
  }
}
```

You simply need to remember that JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, so you can't misspelll the variable names or use a different capitalization than they are written in the Apex code.